# Use of semaphores in read/write threads

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

I have a problem where I have multiple threads(Read threads) where shared data is to be read, no issue so far.
This shared data is to be updated in another single thread(Write thread).

During this write no reads should be done to prevent corrupt data.

My initial thought was to use a semaphore(Posix semaphore, ) after doing some reading.

Using sem_wait() and sem_post() works fine for blocking, decrementing and incrementing the semaphore inside the read threads. As long as the semaphore is not 0, sem_wait() does not block and allow the thread to read the data.

My issue starts here. 
Now I would like to have the condition for the write thread to be opposite of what sem_wait() actually does. I would like the write thread to be blocked as long as the semaphore is larger than zero as this means there is a read thread in progress.

Is there any way for it to block while semaphore is larger than 0 or is there any different approach that could solve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Semaphores are a bad choice for this. POSIX supplies reader/writer locks. But it may actually be best just to use a mutex because it has the least overhead for locking/unlocking.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use POSIX [read-write lock](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_rwlock_destroy.html), where multiple readers can acquire the lock unless there is a writer.

Another option is a lower-level [`seqlock`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seqlock) but it may be trickier to implement and use correctly because it requires a good grasp of the [memory model](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/memory_model) data races and memory order.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use semaphores, and are in a unix-y kind of environment, I think you are stuck with something like this:

```
typedef struct rwl RWL;

struct rwl {
    sem_t  lock;
    sem_t  wread;
    sem_t  wwrite;
    int    nreaders;
    int    nwriters;
};


void RWL_REnter(RWL *l) {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&l->lock);
        l->nreaders++;
        if (l->nwriters) {
            sem_post(&l->lock);
            sem_wait(&l->wread);
        } else {
            sem_post(&l->lock);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void RWL_WEnter(RWL *l) {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&l->lock);
        l->nwriters++;
        if (l->nreaders || l->nwriters > 1) {
            sem_post(&l->lock);
            sem_wait(&l->wwrite);
        } else {
            sem_post(&l->lock);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void RWL_WExit(RWL *l) {
    sem_wait(&l->lock);
    if (--(l->nwriters)) {
        sem_post(&l->wwrite);
    } else while (l->nreaders--) {
        sem_post(&l->wread);
    }
    sem_post(&l->lock);
}

void RWL_RExit(RWL *l) {
    sem_wait(&l->lock);
    if (--(l->nreaders)) {
        sem_post(&l->wread);
    } else if (l->nwriters--) {
        sem_post(&l->wwrite);
    }
    sem_post(&l->lock);
}
```

Functionally, lock is a mutex for the structure, and wwrite, wread serve as condition variables for the writers and readers respectively.  nreaders is required to remember how many concurrent readers there are (since you can't wait on a +tive semaphore ) and nwriters for how many writers are waiting [ you don't want to post blindly in either condition ].